# Google Chrome page load problem (ERR_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: google-chrome

I am having this annoying problem with Google Chrome, although I used to love Chrome I will switch to Firefox if the problem persists.

Sometimes while loading a page Chrome fails and displays ERR_TIMED_OUT error.

[image]

This does not occur every time, in average out of 10 page loads 1 fails. When I hit refresh a couple of times, it will load eventually.

I am using Firefox for a couple of hours now and it seems to work fine.

So far I tried these: clearing cache, switching user profiles, disabling DNS prefetching, disabling detection of connection settings automatically in IE (yes, I don't know why this is here, but I remember having the same problem a few years ago and this worked). I run out of ideas.

How can I prevent this error from happening? Or at least how can I trace the source of this error?

Comment: Maybe you have bad latency?  Try doing a speed test.  This is more likely a network problem than a problem with Chrome.

Comment: You may also try using other DNS server (eg; [openDNS](http://www.opendns.com/start/)) if your internet connection has no issues with speed.

Comment: @tjameson and @Kush: Firefox and IE works fine.

Comment: Got the same issue. Only happens in Chrome with localhost. Very irritating!

Comment: Doesn't Chrome load links on a page automatically in case you need them ?  That may be whe its timing out.  I gave up on CHrome a while ago because of speed issues.

Comment: It's also happening to me in all browsers based on Chromium (Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi). Sometimes it just reloads automatically but it's really irritating since I have to wait for the timeout to happen (30 seconds I guess).